# Installing pciutils on Cygwin and makefile error

Tags: linux, makefile, cygwin, libusb

I want to run a project that communicates with a USB device using [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb). I already have it on Linux, and it works great there, so I want to run it on Windows with [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin). I installed libusb for Windows and libusb in Cygwin, then tried to compile it. It turns out that you need pciutils, unlike on Linux in which it's really easy to get it. In Cygwin it's a problem.

After overcoming some difficulties I managed to get further with my purpose of compiling pciutil in the Cygwin environment. I follwed these steps:

1. Download winio package for Windows and went to Winio\Binaries and copied winio32.dll and winio32.sys to the pciutil directory.
2. Copy config.h/mk from ../win32 to ../lib
3. Go to ..\lib\i386-io-winodws.h and change line 39 to "lib = LoadLibrary("WinIo32.dll");"
4. $ make
5. The make step didn't work. It showed me a makefile error, so I tried to play with it without any luck.

I got this error:

```
gcc   lspci.o ls-vpd.o ls-caps.o ls-ecaps.o ls-kernel.o ls-tree.o ls-map.o common.o lib/libpci.a  -o lspci
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `_outpd'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0xd3): undefined reference to `_outpd'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `_outpw'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x110): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x184): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x1af): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `_outpw'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x242): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x259): undefined reference to `_outpd'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x2d5): undefined reference to `_outpd'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x30c): undefined reference to `_inpd'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x328): undefined reference to `_inpw'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x348): undefined reference to `_inp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x3b2): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x3c6): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x3ed): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x417): undefined reference to `_inpw'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x42f): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x447): undefined reference to `_inp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x457): undefined reference to `_inpd'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x65a): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x666): undefined reference to `_inpd'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x67c): undefined reference to `_outpd'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x688): undefined reference to `_inpd'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x69f): undefined reference to `_outpd'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x6c3): undefined reference to `_outpd'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x729): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x73d): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x751): undefined reference to `_outp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x75d): undefined reference to `_inp'
lib/libpci.a(i386-ports.o):i386-ports.c:(.text+0x778): undefined reference to `_inp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:96: recipe for target 'lspci' failed
make: *** [lspci] Error 1
```

I went to the Makefile, line 96, but I didn't understand what to change there in order to make it work (if you like, I could post the entire makefile too):

```
%: %.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: I am using the 32bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a 32-bit version of Windows you can use the Cygwin port of pciutils. The files in the `win32` subdirectory are actually for the MinGW port, and that's why you get the link errors.

The first thing you should do unpack the source files to a new directory so you can start from fresh. Your changes and modifications aren't necessary to compile it using Cygwin. Be sure not to copy any of the files in the `win32` directory this time, they're not needed. Also don't copy the `winio32` files, you don't need them either. Don't make any changes to any of the files.

The next thing to do is to install the **ioperm** package using Cygwin's `setup-x86.exe`. Type `ioperm` in the search box to quickly find it amongst all the other packages. Once it's been installed run `ioperm -i` from the Cygwin prompt to install the driver that allows applications to do direct I/O.

Next change directory to where you unpacked the fresh copy of pciutils and run the following command from the Cygwin shell:

```
make HOST=i386-pc-cygwin
```

That should be all you need to do to create the library and utilities.

Comment: when I tried to compile my code that in using pci.h headers and can't work without I encounter an error that pci.h is missing. pciutuls was compiled but I dont know why it's didn't linked to lpci.

Comment: Try doing `make HOST=i386-pc-cygwin install` to install the libpci header files and libraries. You may need to run that command an as an administrator. When compiling your code you may need to point the compiler at the locations where the headers and libraries were installed using the `-I` and `-L` options.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.I looked further at the readme again and used `make HOST=i386-pc-cygwin install-lib` which sorted everything out.